# My Laptop has still some Linux in it?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu-12.04

I installed Linux Ubuntu a few days ago. I realised it was a bit overrated and decided to go back to windows. I created a bootable USB stick of Windows 7 on the the same system(Ubuntu). I successfully installed Windows but while trying to do some tweakings, did something wrong that caused the system to not boot anymore. I used my desktop which has Windows to create a USB stick again to reinstall/repair windows. Now when I try to boot using that USB stick, I get an error

```
"error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>"
```

Now, I think grub is concerned with linux/ubuntu only. Since I installed Windows from a USB stick created on Ubuntu, I fear that my Windows got installed on some sort of Linux base which is why it is not recognising the bootable usb that was created on Windows. The same USB stick works fine on other Windows systems. How do I recover windows (Dell Vostro, looping boot screen) and remove that "linux base" or just remove everything(such that nothing windows or linux is left). I'm a noob. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Grub is the boot manager generally installed with Linux, including Ubuntu. However, it sounds like it isn't booting from the USB drive. Are you sure it is setup correctly? (ie: will the USB drive boot the Windows installer on another computer?)

Comment: I recently answered a similar question with details.  See http://superuser.com/questions/1013739/deleted-linux-partition-and-now-grub-rescue-shows-up/1014484#1014484  Not all of that may apply to you, but the part about booting Windows may.

Comment: @Kody Brown yes it works fine on another computer

Comment: @Craig "search" and "chainloader" commands are not recognised by the grub

Comment: Try `insmod chain`, `insmod ntfs`, `set root=(hd0,1)`, `chainloader +1`--The `(hd0,1)` assumes std partitioning.  Here are two pages that may help: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/ and http://www.supergrubdisk.org/ Do you have an MBR or GPT system?  And, are you using UEFI secure boot?  The simplest way may just to repeat what you did at the top of your post--minus some of the tweakings [specifics?] that broke it.  After the Win install, did you do full reboot to prove that it wrote a new MBR [with Win's boot loader]?

Answer (score 1):

In your bios setting when booting (usually tapping f10 or delete to access). Check to see if you can secure erase disk.  Reinstall Windows.

If not, download systemrescuecd, burn iso, boot live image, open gparted and delete partitions / partition table from disk then reinstall Windows.